# Why is this not working? if matrix[i] == something & matrix[i+1] == something I get a Non-conforming array error in R

Tags: r

I don't know what's wrong with this method the input matrix is fine and works with other methods and is correct but I get an error:

> Error in matrix[i, j] == 0 & matrix[i, j + 1] == 0 & matrix[i + 1, j] ==  :
> non-conformable arrays

```
checkToLeft<- function(matrix) {
counter <- 0
  for(i in 1:(nrow(matrix))-1) {
    for (j in 1:(ncol(matrix))-1) {
      if(matrix[i,j]==0 & matrix[i,j+1]==0 & matrix[i+1,j]==255 & matrix[i+1,j+1]==255) {
        counter <- counter + 1
        }
    }
  }
  return(counter)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closing bracket should be

```
1:(nrow(matrix)-1)   # same for the ncol
```

instead of

```
1:(nrow(matrix))-1
```